# Created a PR on one origin - Switched origin and pushed changes to the branch on a different origin. How do I fix this?

Tags: git, github

So I am running into an issue here - Basically I was on a default origin lets call it "mainComp" and in that origin I pushed my branch (MyawesomeCode) and created a PR. Now few days later I started working on something else and changed my origin to "foo" and forgot about it.I then went and pushed some more changes to `MyawesomeCode` branch (not knowing that I am on a different origin "foo" and that the actual pr was on the origin "mainComp") and thats why those changes are not being shown up in the original PR I created. My question is how can I move all those changes to the original origin "main" ?

Comment: `git push [remote name] [branch name]` or use `--set-upstream` to change the default too

Comment: Just add back the original remote and push them there. Note that you *can* have multiple remotes configured at the same time (i.e. have `[remote "origin"]` and `[remote "mainComp"]` and `[remote "foo"]` sections in the local `.git/config`). So configure `mainComp` as a remote again and push there (`git push mainComp MyawesomeCode`).